# What variable expression to use to fetch name of dataset in ADF V2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a dataset defined in ADF V2 of type Azure Storage. In the Connection we need to specify container and in my case the container is going to be the same as the name of the dataset itself. Is there any way I can access name of the dataset dynamically? Because I would then like to clone this dataset and create many datasets with different names and in all the cases container name is going to be the same as their dataset names. I have tried accessing dataset name using @dataset().name and @dataset() also but it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Dhiraj, based on the [System variables in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-system-variables) and [Expressions and functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#introduction) , there is no such expression like `@dataset.name()` or `@dataset()`.

However,you could try to use parameters with dataset to implement your needs.When you create your datasets,you know the name definitely. Please add that name as a default value parameter of dataset like this:

[image]

Then you could refer to the value by using `@dataset().selfName`.(You could view this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#a-dataset-with-a-parameter)

[image]

---

My solution is also a hardcoding way because dataset name can't be referred in dataset inside so far as i found.

Comment: thanks but this is quite not the solution I was looking for -- it is same type of hard coding in a different way.  It means we are specifying dataset name in dataset as well as default parameter value , in 2 places. I was looking for some dynamic solution so we minimize hardcoding.

Comment: @Dhiraj But the dataset name can't be referred in the pipeline runs directly according to the documents. My solution is a workaround and you have to define the dataset name if you want to use it anyway,am i right?

Comment: right, then the answer is that there is no dynamic solution to this as per current ADF v2 features. If I want to create multiple datasets which only differ in names, I would have to specify (hardcode) name in 2 places -- once while naming the dataset itself and second time in the container (so bottom line is twice hardcoding) -- With your approach also it is twice hardcoding, though in a different way. So what you suggest is just a different permutation of the same solution, so it's hardly a solution to the question I posed. At the most we can say ADF v2 provides no such feature.

Comment: @Dhiraj agreed, no such feature to get dataset name in dataset inside so far as i found.I clarify it at the end of my answer.

Comment: @Dhiraj BTW,i suggest you submitting feedback to ADF team to adding this feature in the future:https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory. Thanks a lot.